# why the scaffold doesn't work in odoo-14?

Tags: odoo-14

I have this problem in my terminal when I do this: python3 odoo-bin scaffold product
in **/var/odoo/odoo-14/odoo$**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in 
import odoo
File "/var/odoo/odoo-14/odoo/odoo/**init**.py", line 75, in 
import PyPDF2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing python library.

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

Comment: I had to use venv that's the probleme because i have 2 python versions @Bhavesh Odedra